# Redux/ReactJS: Where should I store visual details of a state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am creating a travel costs calculator. You tell it where/how you are likely to take subway this month and it helps you to figure the best combination of tickets. Main result to show is the best option + price.

I want to make it expandable, so that if user clicked on a total price, it would unwrap (with animation) a table explaining what the price is made of. Oversimplifying a bit, it would be something like the following:

```
< 22 trips a month -> use Ticket class A, it will cost $734 >
   |
   | user clicks on the web or taps on mobile
   |
   v
< 22 trips a month -> use Ticket class A, it will cost $734 >
  - trips 1-10 cost $340 ($34 each)
  - trips 11-20 cost $330 ($33 each)
  - trips 21-22 cost $64 ($32 each)
```

What is a good place to store state about expanded / not-expanded?

1. In the whole app state, because it's still a piece of state as everything else and helps components be real dumb -> Also makes it easier to port between web and native.

   Then clicks on the line will generate actions, will be processed by reducers and will modify some `expanded` key in the state.
2. Inside the components, because it's low level UI animation has nothing to do with the business logic and even with in-app navigation.

   Then clicks will be handled inside the component and they will wrap/unwrap e.g by setting a CSS class.
3. Something different?

What do you use in your apps? Is there some standard pattern for the situations like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your #2 here is correct. Generally, state pertaining to an individual component (opened or closed, tab index, hover, animations, etc.) should be kept in component level state.

You could use the following to set the initial state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        expanded: false
    };
}
```

Then create an onClick function that returns `this.setState({ expanded: true )};`

That is how I would probably handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say #2 also, but I have one question, did this boolean state will be store somewhere (local storage, ...) ? then it would be in the global state, because your initial state boolean will be set from this storage